# Redshift COPY csv in S3 using python

Tags: python, copy, amazon-redshift

HI I have the following function to save a csv file:

```
mysql_cur = mysql_conn.cursor()
mysql_cur.execute('select * from %s where Date > "2018-01-01";' % mysql_table_name  )
description = mysql_cur.description
rows = mysql_cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    c.writerow(row)
```

Then I manually upload the file to an S3 bucket.

Last I run the COPY query:

```
redshift_cur = redshift_conn.cursor()

sql = """copy kpi_kpireport from 's3://clab-migration/kpi.csv' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=ID;aws_secret_access_key=KEY/KEY/pL/KEY'
csv;"""
print(redshift_cur.execute(sql))
```

The COPY command works when I use it in SQL Workbench/J, I am just not sure what I am doing wrong here with the syntax in the execute statement that does not copy any rows.

Comment: What is your question? Is something now working? Are you getting an error message? Does `redshift_conn` work for other things, such as `SELECT 42`?

Comment: What is the error you're getting when you run the COPY command from the Python code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the reason you are not seeing data into Redshift seems like you have not enabled Auto-Commit, hence, your commands executed successfully, but it does `copy` data into `Redshift`, but doesn't commit. Hence, you don't see data when you `select`  by querying from `console` or your `WorkBench/J`.

You should be beginning and committing transaction explicitly.
I'm just giving you a simple working example.

```
import psycopg2


def redshift():

    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='**_dev_**', host='888888888888****.u.****.redshift.amazonaws.com', port='5439', user='******', password='********')
    cur = conn.cursor();

    # Begin your transaction
    cur.execute("begin;")

    cur.execute("copy kpi_kpireport from 's3://clab-migration/kpi.csv' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=ID;aws_secret_access_key=KEY/KEY/pL/KEY' csv;")
    # Commit your transaction
    cur.execute("commit;")
    print("Copy executed fine!")

redshift();
```

Now, if you run above code, you will see the data copied.

If you remove two lines from above code, `cur.execute("begin;")`, `cur.execute("commit;")` run it, even though run successfully without error, you will not see data in Redshift.